# What does a CUDA driver do?

Tags: graphics, driver

I've heard talk of installing a CUDA driver for the new unibody mac (Nvidia 330M) to possibly resolve graphics problems (though it seems it actually doesn't do so). I'm not having problems but I was wondering exactly what the CUDA driver does, if it supplements or replaces the default graphics driver, and if it gives better performance. Please explain!

Comment: CUDA is a SDK. Developers may use CUDA for GPU processing. Graphics problem is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvidia offers a CUDA driver and OpenGL driver, for use with their APIs. The application would need to be recompiled with these options for the .app to use the cuda driver.

Here is the latest info, from a last month...
http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_downloads.html

Scroll down to Mac OS X section for some good non-programmer - adv programmer info.

Comment: That page is a 404 today.  :-(